# NSUserDefaultsProblem

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, nsuserdefaults

I have a simple problem:
I add an object to an NSArray, then I add an object to it then I use the NSUserDefaults way to save the array, but it doesn't work, I mean the array isn't saved and the console sends me this messange:

2011-03-21 23:09:53.994 Project[10490:207] *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    ""
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.

does anybody know how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults only allows you to save basic lightweight objects; for example NSString, NSNumber and NSData. If you want to add another class, you'll have to shoehorn it into an NSData object beforehand. This is pretty simple, usually just a call to `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];`. Note that the objects in the array must implement the NSCoding protocol, which you'll have to add to any of your own custom classes if that's what you want to save.

Also keep in mind NSUserDefaults is meant for lightweight preferences, not application data. If you have a large array of objects, you might be better served by archiving it to its own file or using Core Data (if you feel comfortable using something a little more advanced).

Answer (score 1):

The only types you can save in NSUserDefaults are property list types: NSString, NSDate, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber, NSData. You're probably trying to save an array of objects that aren't one of these types.